# Show with convergence test that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-\cos(\frac{1}{n^2}))$ converges

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, summation

The question is if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-\cos(\frac{1}{n^2}))$ converges or not, according to wolfram it does. d'lambert and cauchy's tests don't seem to be the way to go, so im thinking maybe we can compare it to another sum that we know converges and is larger than the sum above.

But which test to use? The obvious choice is to go with $n^2(1-\cos(\frac{1}{n^2}))$ but now we need to prove that this sum converges and that's really the same problem.

Can anyone think of a good comparison?

Comment: I mean find $A(n) > n(1-\cos(\frac{1}{n^2}))$ such that $\sum A(n)$ converges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $1- \cos^2 \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \leq 2\cdot \left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$. This is true due to the inequality: $1- \cos x = 2\sin^2 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \leq 2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: Ok that indeed solves the question very easily, but why is that inequality true?

Comment: @OriaGruber because [$|\sin x| < |x|$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298/how-to-strictly-prove-sin-xx-for-0x-frac-pi2)

Comment: that was so trivial im embarrased

Answer (score 1):

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$ converges and
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(1-\cos\frac{1}{n^2})}{\frac{1}{n^3}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^4\left(1-\cos\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}=\frac{1}{2}$,

the series converges by the Limit Comparison Test.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : cos($1$/$n^2$) is equivelant to $1$$-\frac{1}{2n^4}$+... as n tends to infinity

Answer (score 0):

The limit comparison test with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ (and two applications of L'hopital's Rule) should do the trick.