# $|\cos(x) - 1| \le |x|$ and $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, inequality

> Using the fact that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are Lipschitz, prove $|\cos(x) - 1| \le |x|$ and $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$.

I have proved that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are Lipschitz, and the above seems really simple, and I am just missing it. Help!

Comment: What Lipschitz constant did you find?

Comment: actually
$$
0\le1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac x2\le \frac{x^2}2
$$

Comment: @egreg I found L = 1. By letting y = 0, I can prove this just like Rick said.

Comment: @Goose719 That's indeed the idea! If the derivative is bounded, then the least upper bound of the absolute value of the derivative is a Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Can someone tell me the use of the fact that $cos$ and $sin$ are Lipschitz.Because even then we need to compute constant $k$.

Comment: For $|\sin x|\le |x|$, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298/how-to-strictly-prove-sin-xx-for-0x-frac-pi2 adn some answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By mean value theorem, there is a $c=c(x,y)$ such that 
$$|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|\leq \underbrace{|\sin(c_{xy})|}_{\leq 1}|x-y|\leq |x-y|$$
take $y=0$ to conclude.
Same for $\sin$.

Comment: Had a brain fart. Thanks.

Comment: there is even equality in the first relation.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that proof of $|\sin x|\le|x|$ in this way might be cyclic. (If we used this inequality to proof $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}x=1$. And if we used the limit of $\sin x/x$ in the proof that derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$. (See one of the proofs on ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Sine_Function )