# Prove $\ \sin(x) < x \ \ \ \forall x \in(0, 2\pi)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Problem : Prove $\sin(x) < x \ \ \  \forall x \in(0, 2\pi)$

Now I have a possible solution for this, using limits and the first derivatives of $\sin(x)$ and $x$, but I don't feel it's a very rigorous or succinct way to prove this. Can any of you find better ways to prove this? My proof is listed below.

---

**Possible Proof**

First we take the limits of both $\sin(x)$ and $x$ as $x \to 0^{+}$.
$$ \lim_{x \to \ 0^{+}}\  \sin(x) = \sin(0) = 0$$
$$ \lim_{x \to \ 0^{+}}\  x  = 0$$

Next we take the derivatives of $\sin(x)$ and $x$. To see how they increase/descrease over the interval $(0, 2\pi)$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ \sin(x)\  = \cos(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \ x\  = 1$$

$$\text{However} \ \ \cos(x) < 1,  \ \forall x \in (0, 2\pi)$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx} \ \sin(x) < \frac{d}{dx} \ x\ ,\ \ \forall x \in (0, 2\pi)$$

This shows that the magnitude at which $\sin(x)$ is increasing is less than that of $x$ over the interval $(0, 2\pi)$, therefore if $\sin(x) \not> x$ as $x \to 0^{+}$, $\sin(x) < x, \ \forall x \in (0, 2\pi)$

$$Q.E.D$$

---

Would you say that this is a satisfactory proof? It doesn't seem particularly satisfactory to me, and it doesn't seem rigorous enough or all that succinct.

Are there better or more efficient/clearer ways to prove this, or problems of these sort of nature? Also if you have any comments about my proof-writing skills please leave them below.

Comment: It's much simpler to say that $g(x)=\sin(x)-x$ is such that $g(0)=0$ and that $g'<0$ over $(0,2\pi)$, because you have only one function to study, instead of two.

Comment: You want to be very careful using derivatives to solve this. One often uses the fact that $\sin x < x$ in a right neighbourhood of $0$ in conjunction with the squeeze theorem to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

There are thus circular reasoning issues. I am hesitant, however, to say that this is entirely incorrect; there are some definitions of $\sin$ where this proof is fine.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that several proofs of this inequality can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298/how-to-strictly-prove-sin-xx-for-0x-frac-pi2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  an easy corollary of the *Mean value theorem*:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on an interval $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$. If $f(a)\le g(a)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ on $(a,b)$, then $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

Note that actually, it is enough to prove it for the interval $(0,\frac\pi2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the easy way.  Travel along the unit circle $x$ units in the positive direction (counterclockwise).  You are at angle $x$ radians.  The coordinates of the point are $(\cos(x), \sin(x))$.

The distance from the point to the $x$-axis is $\sin(x)$ for $0 < x < \pi$; this is shorter than the distance along the circular arc, which is $x$.   Therefore, in the first (and second quadrants) you have   you have $\sin(x) < x$. No calculus is required.

Comment: This is classic and fully rigorous proof for $\sin x < x$. But it does require calculus /analysis in the justification of existence of length of an arc. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you know that $\cos x < 1$ for $0 < x < 2\pi$, then
$$
0 < \int_0^{x} 1-\cos(t) \, dt = x -\sin(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a rigorous proof, but you could also think of it this way:
Consider $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=x$
$$\sin(0)=0$$
Now, the rate of growth of $y=\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ while the rate of growth of $y=x$ is $1$. In the interval $(0,2\pi), \cos(x)<1$ Thus in the interval $(0,2\pi), \sin(x)<x$