# Prove $\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{x}} \gt \frac{x}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Not much explanation needed beyond the heading. I am trying to prove this above statement:  $$\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{x}} \gt \frac{x}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}$$  is true for all $$x>2$$ Any proofs or suggestions on how to get going would be appreciated.

Comment: The inequality is not defined for all real numbers (that's not an answer, just an observation)

Comment: Very true, I am sorry. I will make the edit now.

Comment: @Scuffed Newton It's still wrong.  Add also your attempts.

Comment: @NajKamp, I actually need it true for X>2, I have edited this and really should of put it in when I posted, I'm new at this. I think it will be defined for all x>2.

Comment: What have you tried? What failed? What do you think will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want $$\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{x}} \gt \frac{x}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}$$

When the denominators are non-zero, we can rewrite this as:

$$\frac{\pi}{x} > \sin \frac{\pi}{x} \cos \frac{\pi}{x}$$

Well, for all $p\ne 0$, $$|p|>|\sin p| \ge |\sin p \cos p|.$$

The expression is true for all $x \ne 0 \text{ (and where defined).}$

Comment: Okay, yes, you are correct.  I need to be careful because diving by $-4$ flips the sign of the inequality.

Comment: but then $\sin x > x$ using expansions.. so it would be true for all values of $|x|\geq2$, values of $0\leq |x|<2$ since $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ would become zero at some values//

Comment: YEs!  The expression $\pi - x \sin \pi/x \cos \pi/x $ is even, so you are right!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac \pi {\sin^2 \frac\pi x} > \frac x {\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}
$$
Let $u = \pi/x.$ then $x>2$ means $0<u<\pi/2.$ Then the inequality becomes
$$
\frac u {\sin^2 u} > \frac 1 {\tan u} \quad\text{for } 0<u<\frac \pi 2
$$
and then
$$
u \tan u > \sin^2 u \quad \text{for } 0<u<\frac\pi2.
$$
Since $\sin u < u < \tan u$ for $0<u<\pi/2,$ the inequality follows.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{x}}=\frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{\pi}{x}\sin \frac{\pi}{x}}=\frac{1}{\sin \frac{\pi}{x} / \cos \frac{\pi}{x}}\frac{\pi}{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}\sin \frac{\pi}{x}}=\frac{1}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}\frac{\pi}{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}\sin \frac{\pi}{x}}$$
$$=\frac{x}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}\frac{\pi}{x\cos\frac{\pi}{x}\sin \frac{\pi}{x}}=\frac{x}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}\frac{\pi/x}{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}\sin \frac{\pi}{x}}.$$

$$\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{x}}=\frac{x}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}\frac{\pi/x}{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}\sin \frac{\pi}{x}}.$$

Now, you need to estimate the second factor.

Answer (score -1):

We can cancel out both sides a factor $\sin \frac{\pi}{x}>0$ to obtain

$$\frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{x}} \gt \frac{x}{\tan \frac{\pi}{x}}\iff  \frac{\pi}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{x}} \gt \frac{x}{\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{x}}{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}}$$

$$\iff  \frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{\pi}{x}} \gt \frac{x}{\frac{1}{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}} \iff \frac \pi x> \sin \frac{\pi}{x}\cos \frac{\pi}{x}=\frac12 \sin \frac{2\pi}{x}$$

$$\iff \sin \frac{2\pi}{x}< \frac{2\pi}{x}$$

a well known inequality which holds for $\frac{2\pi}{x}>0$ and therefore for $x>2$.

Refer to the related

- [Prove $\ \sin(x) < x \ \ \ \forall x \in(0, 2\pi)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1806387/505767)
- [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/505767)

Comment: Something wrong with that proof? Thanks for any advice!