# Proof of logarithm inequality without continuity: $\frac{x}{1+x}\le \ln(1+x)\le x$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, alternative-proof

Showing that the logarithm function is continuous in its domain boiled down to proving

$$\frac{x}{1+x}\le \ln(1+x)\le x \ \ \text{for all}\ x >-1.$$

There are quite a few proofs already online. Due to context, however, I need to justify this result

- *without* using continuity of logarithm or exponential functions;
- resorting to neither power series nor integration.

Is there a way?

Comment: What tools can one use here?

Comment: Are you allowed to use differentiation? Ah wait no if not allowed to use continous we can't really use differentiability which is stronger... right?

Comment: Technically not. The problem is before the differentiation chapter of my textbook. Though I would be completely fine with a differentiation proof as long as it does not assume continuity.

Comment: What is your definition of the logarithm function?

Comment: At least in my calculus treatment a long time ago differentiability requires  continuity. Yet there are functions continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. Those functions are rather weird though.

Comment: If using the logarithm definition Dr.MV uses down below maybe it would be useful to rewrite left hand side as $1-\frac{1}{1+x}$

Comment: See here Dr MV's own proof here which uses only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263

Comment: @smcc Thank you for the reference.  How did you find that so quickly?  Most impressive.  -Mark

Comment: You linked to it a day or so ago in answering another question about the limit of $\ln x/x$ that I also answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1$$

for $x>0$.  Then, letting $x\to x+1$ we arrive at the coveted inequalities

$$\frac{x}{x+1}\le \log(1+x)\le x$$

And we are done!

Note that we can also arrive at the inequalities using the integral definition of the logarithm.  Proceeding, we have

$$\log(x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt$$

Then, it is easy to see that for $0<x$,

$$\frac{x-1}{x}=\int_1^x \frac1x\,dt\le \log(x)\le \int_1^x \frac{1}{1}\,dt=x-1$$

And continuity follows from the integral representation also since

$$\begin{align}
|\log(x_2)-\log(x_1)|&\le \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac1{t}\,dt\\\\
&<\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1}\\\\
&\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,x_1\to x_2
\end{align}$$

Comment: The first half of your answer is exactly what I'm looking for. But if I were to in turn prove the Bernouilli's inequality for real numbers, wouldn't that require using derivatives anyway?

Comment: The proof of the version of Bernoulli's inequality with integer exponent does not require differentiation. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Proof_of_the_inequality

Comment: Bernoulli's Inequality as applied here, was for integer exponents.  And its proof relies on elementary induction.

Comment: Indeed, I was referring to the proof for real exponents.

Comment: If you can prove Bernoulli's Inequality for rational exponents, then by a density argument, you can extend this to the reals.  But this is not relevant for the development herein. -Mark

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight! I can now move on to proving continuity for other main elementary functions. I have a feeling that the inequalities mentioned in this post will be most handy in the future to come.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And pleased to hear that this was useful!!  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: Haven't you, by any chance, proven somewhere that $\ |\sin \frac{x}{2} | \leq |\sin x|$ with similar restrictions (*i.e*, no continuity)? ;)

Comment: To be fair, I now see that for my purposes it was enough to show $\ |\sin \frac{x}{2} | \leq |\sin x|$ is valid for some interval centered around $0$. But instead the problem is circumvented altogether using a different inequality "proved" with a unit circle. I was initially reluctant to use such an argument due to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298/how-to-strictly-prove-sin-xx-for-0x-frac-pi2). For my purposes, a geometry arguement is probably rigorous enough.

Comment: The inequality is obviously not true in general (e.g., For $x=\pi$, $|\sin(x)|=0$ and $|\sin(x/2)|=1$).

Comment: Note that $f(x)=\sin(x)-\sin(x/2)=\sin(x/2)(2\cos(x/2)-1)$, which is greater than zero when $\cos(x/2)>1/2$ and $\sin(x/2)>0$ ( $0<x<2\pi/3$) or $\cos(x/2)<1/2$ and $\sin(x/2)<0$ ($0>x>-2\pi/3$) for $-\pi < x< \pi$.