# Given that $I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2nx}{\sin x}dx$,how to prove that $I_n\leq 1+\ln\sqrt{2n-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, definite-integrals

It's given that $$I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2nx}{\sin x}dx,$$and I need to prove that $$I_n\leq1+\ln\sqrt{2n-1}.$$
I have got that $$I_n-I_{n-1}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2nx}{\sin x}dx-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2(n-1)x}{\sin x}dx\\=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{[\sin nx-\sin(n-1)x][\sin nx+\sin(n-1)x]}{\sin x}dx\\=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\cos\frac{(2n-1)x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot2\sin\frac{(2n-1)x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}{\sin x}dx\\=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin[(2n-1)x]\sin x}{\sin x}dx\\=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin[(2n-1)x]dx\\=\frac{1}{2n-1}.$$
Then it's easy to know that $$I_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2r-1}.$$
That's all the work I've done. What should I do next?

Comment: You're basically done. Define the harmonic numbers $H_n = \sum_{i\le n} 1/i.$ Then $I_n = H_{2n-1} - 0.5 H_{n-1}$. Standard bounds on the Harmonic numbers, [e.g. this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534053/on-the-harmonic-number-h-n-upper-and-lower-classical-bounds-which-of-thos), show that $ 0.5 + \log n \le H_n \le 1 + \log n, $ from which the bound you want to show follows (you might need to use $\log 2 < 1$ somewhere). You can probably also directly show the bound using techniques in the answers to the question I linked.

Answer (score 2):

**By induction:**
For $n=1,2$, $I_1=1,I_2=\frac{4}{3}<1+\ln\sqrt{3}$ is easy to check.
Suppose $I_n<1+\ln\sqrt{2n-1}$,
then
$$I_{n+1}=I_n+\frac1{2n+1}<1+\ln\sqrt{2n-1}+\frac1{2n+1}.$$
We need to prove
$$1+\ln\sqrt{2n-1}+\frac1{2n+1}<1+\ln\sqrt{2n+1},$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac1{2n+1}<\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}.$$
This follows from the [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862356/proof-of-logarithm-inequality-without-continuity-fracx1x-le-ln1x-le?noredirect=1):
$$\frac{x}{1+x}<\ln(1+x),\quad \forall x>0,$$
just take $x=\frac{2}{2n-1}$.