# Prove that $\left|\sin x\right|\leq|x|,\;\;\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

After doing a lot of proofs, I received feedback that some of these proofs may be questionable if we don't show our assumption of $\sin{x}$. We found out that this statement, although basic, posed challenges. Here it is:

> Prove that $\left|\sin x\right|\leq|x|,\;\;\forall \;x\in \Bbb{R}.$

Note: This question is quite different from [how to strictly prove $\sin x<x$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298/how-to-strictly-prove-sin-xx-for-0x-frac-pi2) because I am considering the whole of $\Bbb{R}.$ It is not a duplicate!

Comment: @David G. Stork: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Integrate $\cos x$.

Comment: I think you can use Rolle's theorem on $f(x)=sinx.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x> 0$. By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there exists $\zeta\in(0,x)$ with $$\left|\sin x-\sin0\right|=|f'(\zeta)||x-0|.$$
Since the derivative of sine is bounded by $1$, this gives $|\sin x|\leqslant |x|.$ The same argument applies to the case where $x<0$, and for $x=0$ it is trivial. Hence we have $\left|\sin x\right|\leqslant |x|$ for all $x\in\mathbf{R}$.