# Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} \sin x =\sin c$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition

Tags: calculus

Proof. $\forall \epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Now $\forall x$, if $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|\sin x -\sin c|=|2\cos\frac{x+c}{2} \sin\frac{x-c}{2}|\le 2|\sin \frac{x-c}{2}|\le 2|\frac{x-c}{2}|=|x-c|<\delta=\epsilon $, which completes the proof.

The proof above uses $|\sin x|\le |x|$, which is easy to show geometrically. However, I am afraid it is not rigorous. Can anyone tell me how to show $|\sin x|\le |x|$ without using derivative or Taylor expansion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125298/how-to-strictly-prove-sin-xx-for-0x-frac-pi2

Comment: It depends on how is $\sin$ defined. Here is huge discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/3736280#3736280 of several possible cases. Without derivative, geometry and Taylor I brought, for example, axiomatic definition.

Comment: Why $|sinx|≤|x|$ is not rigorous? It is well established and at least in my opinion rigour enough. In that sense you also used $cost\leq1$ without showing it, trigonometric identities and absolute values properties without showing them also...It can go on forever.

Comment: Thanks to you all.